# Why does this PHP code output 000000?

Tags: php

```
<?php
$string1 = "AMITABH BACHAN";
$string2 = "RAJNIKANTH";
$stringParts1 = str_split($string1);
$stringParts2 = str_split($string2);
for ($i = 0 ; $i < strlen($string1); $i++)
for ($j = $i ; $j < strlen($string2); $j++) {
if ($stringParts1[$i]==$stringParts2[$j]) {
echo $string1[$i] + '\n';
}
}
?>
```

What am i doing wrong here? On IDEONE it produces no output. On PHP Designer 8 it outputs 000000

Comment: Your array is $stringParts1, but you are accessing $string1[$i].

Answer (score 3):

Basic PHP syntax: [Strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) concatenate with `.`. You're doing **MATH**:

```
echo $string1[$i] + '\n';
                  ^---
```

Plus, your `\n` is pointless. `'\n'` is two chars: `\` and `n`. `"\n"` is a newline char.

You want

```
echo $string1[$i] . "\n";
```

instead

Comment: It should also be noted that shorthand loops without brackets are only for single lines of code after it, where in this case OP has several. This will not work as expected.

Comment: @steve: yeah, the code's ugly. but the inner loop does have {}, so it's effectively a one-liner anyways.